# Let $V$ an inner product space, and $U$ a subspace of $V$. Prove $P^*_U = P_U$ (projection over U).

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations, inner-products, projection

Edit: I have made progress via the comments and now i wonder if my proof is Ok.

By theoreom we know $V$ = $U$ $\oplus$ $U^\bot$.

Suppose some $v$ $\in$ $V$ such that $v=u+u'$ for some $u \in U$ and some $u' \in U^\bot$.

By inner product we will have:

$<u,u>$ = $<v,P_U^*(u)>$ = $<u+u',P_U^*(u)>$ = $<u,P_U^*(u)>$ + $<u',P_U^*(u)>$

Since $u' \bot P_U^*(u)$ we have $<u,u>$ = $<u,P_U^*(u)>$,

thus resulting in $P_U(u) = u = P_U^*(u)$.

This implements $P_U = P_U^*$.

Does this current proof work?

Comment: What does $P^*u$ mean?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) guide on how to format your question with MathJax. Also, would be nice to write down your attempts at solving the question, regardless of whether they have mistakes :) Explaining what each of the symbols mean is also highly encouraged.

Comment: You say "B is an orthonormal basis" but also "I don't have an orthonomal basis". Which is it ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is the conjugated projection over U

Comment: @V.S.e.H. thank you so much i edited my question right now to better fit the format

Comment: @Digitallis i meant that is the theorem I have seen in class about projection, but in the details of this question there isn't such a basis

Comment: There's nothing in the formula for $P_u(v)$ that has anything to do with $U$, something's wrong.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it a bit nicer. Can you clarify what $^*$ is? I.e. conjugate transpose, etc. Can you also clarify which inner product you're considering, i.e. the standard inner product?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. * means the conjugated transpose exactly, and the inner product isn't given in the question. I might have mixed some stuff up including a formula I saw in the lecture that has to do with a standard inner product maybe?

Comment: Okay, please include your attempt at proof in the question, where exactly you're struggling, and include the tag solution-verification, otherwise it will most likely be marked as a dupe (question has been answered numerous times already, see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4446640/443030) )

Comment: @V.S.e.H. would this be ok?